# How would I combine multiple methods in to one method

Tags: c#, xaml, controls

I have 15 fields that do practically the same thing:

```
    private void TextboxMessage1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      SaveMessage(TextboxMessage1.Text, TextboxMessageSeconds1.Text.ToInteger(), 1);
    }

    private void TextboxMessage2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      SaveMessage(TextboxMessage2.Text, TextboxMessageSeconds2.Text.ToInteger(), 2);
    }

    private void TextboxMessage3_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      SaveMessage(TextboxMessage3.Text, TextboxMessageSeconds3.Text.ToInteger(), 3);
    }

etc
```

Which calls SaveMessage:

```
private void SaveMessage(string textboxMessageText, int seconds, int messagenumber)
{
  var msg = _configman.MyConfig.MessageConfigs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MessageNumber == messagenumber);

  if (msg == null)
  {
    var msgconfig = new MessageConfig();
    msgconfig.Seconds = seconds;
    msgconfig.Command = textboxMessageText;
  }
  else
  {
    msg.MessageNumber = messagenumber;
    msg.Command = textboxMessageText;
    msg.Seconds = seconds;
  }
  _configman.SaveConfig();
}
```

My form:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxMessage1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
<TextBox x:Name="TextboxMessage1" Height="23" Margin="49,19,158,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextChanged="TextboxMessage1_TextChanged"/>
<Button x:Name="ButtonMessage1" Content="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="689,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Background="#FFFB8686" Click="ButtonMessage1_Click"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxMessage2" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
<TextBox x:Name="TextboxMessage2" Height="23" Margin="49,44,158,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextChanged="TextboxMessage2_TextChanged"/>
<Button x:Name="ButtonMessage2" Content="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="689,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Background="#FFFB8686"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxMessage3" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
<TextBox x:Name="TextboxMessage3" Height="23" Margin="49,68,158,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextChanged="TextboxMessage3_TextChanged"/>
<Button x:Name="ButtonMessage3" Content="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="689,69,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Background="#FFFB8686"/>
```

Is there a way to make the TextChanged cover all of my textboxes so I don't have to create a TextChanged for each textbox??

They are numbered 1-15 such as TextboxMessage1, TextboxMessage1, etc.

Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: This is why people use MVVM. This kind of thing becomes extremely simple with MVVM. Your life will become much easier, and your code much simpler and more readable, if you learn MVVM, and learn proper XAML techniques like StackPanel and grid layouts, and Styles. You should have one UserControl or DataTemplate that is instantiated fifteen times by an ItemsControl. But that's a bit of a learning curve and if you're too far down the road to start over, both of the answers below have good ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the same "generic" callback like "TextboxMessage_TextChanged" for each of your TextChanged events.
Then:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextboxMessage1" Height="23" Margin="49,19,158,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextChanged="TextboxMessage_TextChanged"/>
```

```
private void TextboxMessage_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
  int index = int.Parse(tb.Name.Substring("TextboxMessage".Length));
  TextBox secondTextBox = (TextBox)this.FindName("TextboxMessageSeconds" + index);
  SaveMessage(tb.Text, secondTextBox.Text.ToInteger(), index);
}
```

Is that something like this that you expect ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to create a new class with an `int` property that inherits from `TextBox`

```
//Come up with a better name
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your xaml change the property type to `CustomTextBox` (or whatever you name it).  Make sure to add the `Number` property and change the `TextChanged` property to "TextBoxSave_TextChanged":

```
<CustomTextBox x:Name="TextboxMessage1" Height="23" Margin="49,19,158,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextChanged="TextBoxSave_TextChanged" Number="1"/>
```

Then in your code behind add a new method `TextBoxSave_TextChanged()`

```
//You can name it whatever, I would keep the "_TextChanged" suffix though
private void TextBoxSave_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Cast sender to your new CustomTextBox type
    CustomTextBox txtBox = ((CustomTextBox)sender);

    SaveMessage(txtBox.Text, txtBox.Text.ToInteger(), txtBox.Number);
}
```

---

Ed's suggestion:

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    #region Number Property
    public int Number
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NumberProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Number), typeof(int), typeof(CustomTextBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(0));
    #endregion Number Property

    #region Seconds Property
    public int Seconds
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SecondsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SecondsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Seconds), typeof(int), typeof(CustomTextBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(0));
    #endregion Seconds Property
}
```

TextChanged handler:

```
//  You can name it whatever, I would keep the "_TextChanged" suffix though
private void TextBoxSave_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Cast sender to your new CustomTextBox type
    CustomTextBox txtBox = (CustomTextBox)sender;

    SaveMessage(txtBox.Text, txtBox.Seconds, txtBox.Number);
}
```

XAML usage:

```
<local:CustomTextBox 
    Number="1"
    Seconds="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextboxMessageSeconds1}"
    TextChanged="TextBoxSave_TextChanged" 

    x:Name="TextboxMessage1" 
    Height="23" 
    Margin="49,19,158,0" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    />
```

But really, this is a poor substitute for writing a proper UserControl.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I'd still have to create 15 of them since the "3" would have to be hard coded, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I missed that the int's were different.  Give me a second to edit

Comment: Just made an update that will allow you to access a new property of your control.

Comment: I like it! Let me try it out real quick. Ty!

Comment: @maccettura The second parameter to SaveMessage() is parsing the text from a different control (TextMessageSecondsN vs TextMessage), so CustomTextBox also needs a dependency property so he can bind using ElementName to the other control. Or he could steal the FindName code from Gizmo's answer.

Comment: @EdPlunkett great catch!  Although I am not exactly certain how to  implement that (unless I am over thinking it).  I am not very familiar with WPF/Xamarin/Forms in general.  Mostly an MVC developer.

Comment: @maccettura Well, he may as well just stick with the awful (yet much less awful than the original!) code Gonzo suggested. Would you mind if I append the code for the dependency property to your answer?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I wouldn't mind at all, in fact I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: @maccettura I'm getting bizarre errors from VS trying to test my code. Hmm

Comment: [I'm getting this unresolved issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/47602/debugging-textchanged-event-causes-wpf-application.html). UFB. Oh wait, [there's a workaround](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/39191/debugger-wont-stop-execution-instead-itd-crash-app.html).

Comment: I feel lucky to not have much familiarity with WPF now haha

Comment: @maccettura Ha yeah, it can be trying at times, especially when you're learning it. This was more of a VS bug though.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I may be biased but I think using properties of the form is a better idea then string manipulation and having to find the control over and over.

Comment: Yes. You can go farther in that same direction and wrap the checkbox, both textboxes, and the button in a UserControl that handles everything internally. Or better yet write a little viewmodel and template it -- then WPF really shines. But I don't have time to write it right now.